# esp-12 power supply + backup by 4F capacitor 5.5v + ME2149, is it working?

Tags: esp8266, supercapacitor, backup

I made my own energy meter using esp-12, I need to save data to esp spiffs when loss grid power, In this case, I do not need wifi than esp turn to modem-sleep mode, so working current is about 20 - 25mA and I think 5 seconds is enough to save data. After searching quite a lot I choose using a super capacitor to backup power, it is 4F 5.5V. Here the diagram, is this diagram working?
[image]

Here datasheet of ME2149 [ME2149 Datasheet PDF](http://file2.dzsc.com/product/17/07/12/1127976_150339724.pdf)

Module ME2149 here [Aliexpress ME2149 Module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Boost-0-8-6V-to-3-3V-DC-DC-Step-Up-Board-Converter-Module-For-ESP8266/32924921357.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.2d734c4dohboeT)

Super Capacitor here [Aliexpress Super capacitor](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/super-capacitor-farad-capacitor-combination-type-5-5V-0-5F-1F-2F-3-5F-4F-5F/33016075482.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.2d734c4dohboeT)

My question is this diagram is working?

Thanks

Edit: the capacitor wiring is reversed, my mistake when edit image, pls pass it

Comment: if your 5v supply doesn't blow up, the circuit should work. you might limit the cap's current, especially because you don't have a big load.

Comment: Thanks, what's problem with the 5v supply? My 5v power supply has 3.5w power, is it because the amount of capacitor? Do I need to change the power supply to 5w or 10W power? If I reduce the capacitor to 2F 5.5V, is it enough to power esp for 5s?